Scaling of objective function changes convergence
I am trying to solve a nonlinear program using the global optimization solver BARON. The problem has roughly 2e4 variables and also several thousand equality and inequality constraints. Being aware of the necessity of scaling the variables, objective function range, and constraint coefficients to similar orders of magnitude for numerical reasons, I experimented a little and observed the following:
Starting from a point where all mentioned quantities are roughly between 0 and 100, the problem tends to get solved much faster when I then divide the objective function by increasing numbers (say, 1e1 to 1e6). Constraint violations are within tolerances.
This increases the difference in order of magnitude of the coefficients, so I would expect a worse outcome. Does someone have a hint for what could be going on here/what I could check to understand this?

Are you saying you divide all the objective coefficients by the same number (in which case what do you mean by "difference in order of magnitude"), or are you saying you divide each coefficient by a larger divisor than the previous coefficient (which would radically change the problem)?

I divide all coefficients by the same number. The larger the number, the faster the solver seems to converge. Difference in order of magnitude: coefficients of objective as compared to coefficients of constraints (which remain unaffected).

What criterion does the solver use for "convergence"? Relative (percentage) convergence should be unaffected by the scaling (give or take rounding error), but absolute convergence would be triggered faster if you scaled the objective without comparably scaling the convergence limit.

Interesting thought! The solver seems to use both (the manual isn't that helpful in detailing these things). I should have been more precise about "convergence": it's not only that the solver reports convergence earlier. Rather, the absolute gap between upper and lower bound decreases faster (and sometimes, only the scaled objective functions lead to upper bounds and convergence at all). Purely speculative: could this have impact on the appearance of the Lagrangian, where the impact of the actual objective is diminished:
L(x,lambda)=1/alpha * f(x) + lambda * g(x) as alpha is increased
